# Assign looped img url to div

Tags: javascript, html, loops

Attempting to recreate a Netflix app in HTML, CSS and JS to support my learning and become more proficient at JS. I want to give each div a background image from an object. The object contains 20 or so images of which I have looped through to get each respective url.

```
const getMovies = () => {
    const movieEndpoint = '/discover/movie';
    const requestParams = `?api_key=${tmdbKey}`;
    const urlToFetch = `${tmdbBaseUrl}${movieEndpoint}${requestParams}`;

    fetch(urlToFetch)
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
    .then(data => {
        const jsonResponse = data;
        movies = jsonResponse.results;
        console.log(movies);

        for (const movie of movies) {
            const fullSource = `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie.backdrop_path}`;
            console.log(fullSource);
        }        
    })
};
```

This successfully logs each url to the console, the trouble I have now is assigning them as backgrounds to existing div elements I have in a similar fashion. I have attempted to write a for loop to go through the divs and then change the background using style.backgroundImage = `url(${fullSource})` but this doesn't work for me.

HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="category">
  <div class="film"></div>
  <div class="film"></div>
  <div class="film"></div>
  <div class="film"></div>
  <div class="film"></div>
  <div class="film"></div>
  <div class="film"></div>
  <div class="film"></div>
  <div class="film"></div>
  <div class="film"></div>
  <div class="film"></div>
  <div class="film"></div>
</div>
```

I have styled the divs in css haven't been able to find a successful method to assign the backgrounds.

To be clear, I would like to populate the divs with a random image from the object using the urls that have been populated.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  {
      image: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/1036/200/300.jpg?hmac=VF4u-vITiP0ezQiSbE3UBvxHDFf8ZqJDycaAIoffsCg'
  },
  {
      image: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/106/200/300.jpg?hmac=qnjqfh7hXrQF9MAA1T3JOgK3dhnLfxOo-HkzhyZoB2g'
  },
  {
      image: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/1036/200/300.jpg?hmac=VF4u-vITiP0ezQiSbE3UBvxHDFf8ZqJDycaAIoffsCg'
  }
]

for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
  const element = document.getElementById(`category-${index}`);
  element.style.backgroundImage = `url(${data[index].image})`;
  element.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
  element.style.backgroundColor = "#f3f3f3";
  element.style.backgroundSize = 'auto';
  // element.style.backgroundPosition = '100vh 100vh';
  element.style.width= '100%';
  element.style.height = '100vh'
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div id="category-0">Background Image 1</div>
  <div id="category-1">Background Image 2</div>
  <div id="category-2">Background Image 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmad but this isn't what the ask is, I can do it statically like this but I want to fill each div with a random image from the object.

Comment: HI @Chaffexd, I have updated the answer, I hope this would be helpful.